# Facebook API - How to like a comment from a Milestone

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a program that automatically likes comments to a certain fan page. The program works perfectly for comments in response to "normal" posts but, if a user post a comment in a milestone post, the program can't like it.

I always get the "(#100) Error finding the requested story" error for those posts.

Below you can see the full error that is returned:

```
{
   "error":{
      "message":"(#100) Error finding the requested story",
      "type":"OAuthException",
      "code":100
   }
}
```

My access token has the following permissions:

- publish_stream
- publish_actions
- manage_pages

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oliver, I remember that 2 years ago I faced a similiar problem. Problem was that milestones still were not returned in api call as "normal" status updates/ posts. You might want to refer to the actual facebook documentation to clear that this has been either changed or still is the case! Greetz!

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichaelSchwark ! The weird thing is that I can get those comments using my program and can even post replies to them. The only thing that I can't do it do Like them...